# Webpack - Correct way to change dependencies before build

Tags: jquery, webpack, requirejs, amd

I'm doing a migration of a RequireJS (AMD) project to Webpack.

I have a dependency like `requirejs-dplugins/jquery!attributes/classes,effects`

Inside this `requirejs-dplugins/jquery` I have a piece of code that translates the `attributes/classes,effects` into

`return ["core"].concat(deps.split(/, */)).map(function (amid) {
  return "jquery/src/" + amid;
});`

How to do the same on Webpack?
Is it a Plugin?
Is it a loader that somehow can change the dependency?

Thanks in advance.